# Firebase Google Sign Error : sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I linked google login to a app which is already in play store. It's not working properly on Emulators. But It works on real physical devices properly. Below is the error showing

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

What I did:

- Flutter clean and pub get
- Uninstall the app and run it
- Checked SHA keys (Play console and local), It's correct.
- Downloaded the google-services.json. replaced it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase UI authentication with google fails with message (code:10 message:10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10)

Comment: @AlexMamo This works properly in physical devices. I updated it on playstore. it works properly. But not works in emulator